# Sending E-mails from different SMTPClients.Host

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, smtpclient, clients

The main problem is that to send an E-mail from G-mail, you need to use smtp.gmail.com as the host, and the port number 587.

```
Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient
    SMTPServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SMTPServer.Port = 587
    SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
```

However, for Hotmail, I would need a different Host and Port, smtp.live.com. Other E-mail clients would therefore require more different hosts. Is there a way, to address all of them without listing all possible E-mail host names and ports?

If not, what alternative is there to supporting all the E-mail hosts without throwing an error?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a choice with this. If you want to use a third party mail server, you have to play by their rules. This includes using the config settings that they specify.

I'm not sure how you would expect to be able to send via Hotmail if you don't tell your software how to contact the Hotmail server.

Your software can only find the appropriate server if it is given the relevant server address and port number.